# How to assign default value for v-model data object

Tags: vue.js

Here i want to set default value for `sendqnt` and `recieveqnt`

```
    export default{
    data: function(){

        return{

     businessforCustomer:false,
    transactionData:{
       business:{},
       senditems:{
         sendqnt:0,
       },
       recieveitems:{
         recieveqnt:0,
       },
    },
   }
  }
```

those to data is set to v-model inside this loop

```
                      <tr v-for="ri in transactionData.recieveitems">
                        <td>{{ri.item_name}}</td>
                         <td>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Item Quantity" v-if="" v-model.number="ri.recieveqnt" >
                         </td>
                      </tr>
```

and

```
                    <tr v-for="si in transactionData.senditems">
                         <td>{{si.item_name}}</td>
                         <td><input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Item Quantity" v-model.number="si.sendqnt">
                         </td>
                     </tr>
```

thanks in advance.

" set transactionData.senditems "

```
axios.get('/api/transactions/getItems')
       .then(function (response){
         app.transactionData.senditems = response.data;
         console.log(response);
       })
       .catch(function (response){
         console.log(response);
       })
```

Comment: share how you set `transactionData.senditems` ? I think it is being replaced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the response it not an array - it is ignored. If it is an array - the attribute `receiveqnt` of each item is set to 0 if it is missing.

```
axios.get('/api/transactions/getItems')
       .then(function (response){
         if(Object.prototype.toString.call(response.data) === '[object Array]') app.transactionData.receiveitems = response.data.map((item) =>
         {
           item.recieveqnt = item.recieveqnt || 0;
           return item;
         });
         else app.transactionData.receiveitems = [];
         console.log(response, app.transactionData.receiveitems);
       })
       .catch(function (response){
         console.log(response);
       })
```